# How to extract all files of any commit to a folder/archive from a Git Repository?

Tags: git, file, backup, directory, archive

I have a Git Repository. I want to export all files and folders from my  repository history, based on the different commits, into a folder. But I want to export all commits and branches separately. A sort of backup/archive for my git repository.

For example if I have a repository history of:

-v2.0 My Latest commit -v1.0 My Initial commit

I want to export all files and folders of these different commits into separate folders. I want the files as normal complete files not as a difference patch.

For example the folders "/MyGitBackup/Master/v1.0" and "/MyGitBackup/Master/v2.0" which should include the files of the according commits.

How can I achieve this? Is a GUI tool capable of this or something similar? I use a Windows machine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git worktree <path> <commit>` that enables to checkout different commits to different directories.
So, execute the following commands in your working directory:

```
git worktree add /MyGitBackup/Master/v1.0 <v1.0 commit hash or tag>
git worktree add /MyGitBackup/Master/v2.0 <v2.0 commit hash or tag>
```

Answer (score 2):

That sounds like a waste of space. But sure it's possible:

- For each revision, as per the `git rev-list` command
- Run `git archive revision` with the appropriate flags

This is one way to export the content of each revision in `master` to a separate folder in a sub-directory of `archive/`:

```
git rev-list master | while read rev; do
    echo creating archive for $rev
    mkdir -p archive/$rev
    git archive $rev | (cd archive/$rev; tar x)
done
```

Comment: This makes folders named after the checksum, is there a more human readable way or a way to name the folders chronically. Which language is this script?

Comment: This is Bash. In Windows, you can run it in a Git Bash shell, which is part of a standard Git installation. Yes it's possible to adjust the script to derive the names from the commit date. It's also possible to use some sort of count. In your example you haven't specified where v1.0 and v2.0 would come from. Obviously the directory names would have to be unique. If you tell me how you would like it, I can try to accommodate.

Comment: I want to name the folders first after the commit date and after the 10  first characters of the commit comment. I want if I select the "Name A-Z"-sort-option my folders are ordered chronically in my file explorer.