# Equivalent of git-archive direct to disk, without any tar processing

Tags: git, optimization, jgit, gitpython

I'm analyzing revision histories, using `git-archive` to get the files at a particular revision (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40811494/1168342).

The approach works, but I'm trying to optimize for projects with many revisions. Much processing is wasted archiving (via tar) and back to a files in another directory (via tar again).

I'm looking for a way to do this without involving `tar`, something like a `git cp $revision $dest/`. Here's what I've explored so far:

- I could use the `git reset $revision --hard` approach with a file copy, but it renders parallelization of the analysis void, unless I create multiple copies of the repo (one for each thread/process).
- There is a [Java project using JGit called Doris](https://github.com/gingerswede/doris) that accomplishes this with low-level operations, but it breaks when there are weird files (e.g., links to other repos). As git has evolved, there are a lot of special cases, so I don't want to do this at a low-level if possible.
- I know there's a git API for Python, but its [archive feature](http://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#module-git.repo.base) also uses tar. For the same reasons as above, I didn't want to code this at too low a level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
mkdir <path> &&
GIT_INDEX_FILE=<path>/.git git --work-tree=<path> checkout <revision> -- . &&
rm <path>/.git
```

The `git checkout` step will overwrite the index, so to make this parallelize well, we can just point the index file into the target.  There's one file name that's pretty sure to be safe: `.git`!

(This is like a lighter weight version of `git worktree add` that also avoids recording the new extracted tree as an active work-tree.)

Edit to add a side note (I expect the OP is aware of this, but for future reference): note that `git archive` applies certain `.gitattributes` filters that this technique will not apply.  In particular, `git checkout` will not obey `export-ignore` and `export-subst` directives.

Comment: I think the worktree/.git index name will work so long as the worktree and repo are on the same filesystem.  Putting the scratch index in the local repo with a junk name always works.

Comment: @jthill: I tested this with /tmp (a separate file system) as the target, with the source repo on a regular file system. That's only one particular OS, but it does have the same limit on cross-device links as most others.

Comment: Hunh.  I wonder why there's a restriction on read-trees `--index-output` but not GIT_INDEX_FILE, then, or perhaps that doc's out of date, it reads "While the command is operating, the original index file is locked
with the same mechanism as usual.  The file must allow
to be rename(2)ed into from a temporary file that is
created next to the usual index file; typically this
means it needs to be on the same filesystem as the index
file itself, and you need write permission to the
directories the index file and index output file are
located in."

Comment: @jthill: I have not investigated, but I suspect `git checkout` either notices that the current index does not exist and simply creates and populates it unlocked, or creates the `.lock` file as `<work-dir>/.git.lock` here (if so that could collide with a real file in the repository).

Comment: I'd also recommend to maybe explore the `git worktree` command (available in recent Git versions right away, and in older ones—in the form of a contrib script). Basically it allows to easily do multiple checkouts of different revisions into different FS directories—all having their own index files (obviously) but sharing the object store of the repository). Basically that's `git worktree add -f --detach $dstdir $rev`.

Comment: @kostix the worktree option has a fair amount of processing. I'm not sure if it's as much as the tarring involved with archive, but I avoided it because it looks a lot like it's comparable to clone (at least that's the feeling I got when I saw the feedback messages it printed).

Comment: @Fuhrmanator, on appropriate filesystems it will certainly not clone the object store. It will still create the index file and then check out its contents (i.e. it'll do `git read-tree` & `git checkout-index` at a minimum). But I'm afraid no plumbing solution would allow you to "just check out" bypassing creation and population of the index. IIUC the only way to achieve this is to recursively do `git ls-files`, parse its output and do `git cat-file blob …` for each blob you find. But that's what—I perceive—you wanted to avoid in the first place.

Comment: I compared the results of my analysis process on the folder created by this method, and they are the same. The fact that there's no second process to de-tar the archive is a huge savings. I'm not in the benchmarking business to give a quantitative answer of the improvement, but this answer is a winner for me.

Comment: @kostix that's why I described this being sort of a lighter-weight `git worktree add`. Adding a worktree will add the auxiliary index and HEAD, but will also record the added worktree and write a `.git` file. At some point you'd want to run `git worktree prune` to clean them up. This sneaky checkout method avoids that.

Comment: I confirm this works in my paralellized pipeline (using Python for control flow). Accepting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In JGit the `ArchiveCommand` implements what `git archive` does and also provides several archive file formats out of the box. However, the `ArchiveCommand` can be extended with custom archive formats.

A custom format needs to implement the `Format` interface and register it with `ArchiveCommand::registerFormat`. Even though the corresponding API seems to be designed with a single output file in mind, it should be possible to output the contents to a directory.